# How can I declare a function that optionally takes a callback, and returns a Promise only if there is no callback?

Tags: generics, overloading, typescript2.0, union-types

TypeScript v2.0.2
on a Mac running El Capitan 10.11.6

I have a single function that performs an async operation,
and:

- either takes a callback, and returns nothing, calling the callback
  later,
- or doesn't take a callback, and returns a Promise, that resolves later.

It seems that I've been had similar code work,
(see https://github.com/psnider/mongodb-adaptor/blob/master/src/ts/MongoDBAdaptor.ts)
but right now this is failing, 
and I can't figure out why!

```
// these declarations look correct to me, the caller uses one or the other
declare abstract class SlimDocumentDatabase<T> {
    create(obj: T): Promise<T>
    create(obj: T, done: (error: Error, result?: T) => void): void
}

class SlimAdaptor<DocumentType> implements SlimDocumentDatabase<DocumentType> {
    create(obj: DocumentType, done?: (error: Error, result?: DocumentType) => void) : void | Promise<DocumentType> {
        if (done) {
            done(undefined, obj)
            return
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve<DocumentType>(obj)
        }
    }
}
```

I can get this to compile by removing the return type specifications from the implementation of create(), by replacing them with **any**. But this seems so wrong!

Here is the code in the TypeScript Playground:
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20abstract%20class%20SlimDocumentDatabase%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20create(obj%3A%20T)%3A%20Promise%3CT%3E%0A%20%20%20%20create(obj%3A%20T%2C%20done%3A%20(error%3A%20Error%2C%20result%3F%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%3A%20void%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aclass%20SlimAdaptor%3CDocumentType%3E%20implements%20SlimDocumentDatabase%3CDocumentType%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20create(obj%3A%20DocumentType)%3A%20Promise%3CDocumentType%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20create(obj%3A%20DocumentType%2C%20done%3A%20ObjectCallback%3CDocumentType%3E)%3A%20void%0A%20%20%20%20create(obj%3A%20DocumentType%2C%20done%3F%3A%20(error%3A%20Error%2C%20result%3F%3A%20DocumentType)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%3A%20void%20%7C%20Promise%3CDocumentType%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(done)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20done(undefined%2C%20obj)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve%3CDocumentType%3E(obj)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/427#issuecomment-257648196

In short, the code in the class definition must include declarations as well as the implementation.

In the code example above, linked to the TypeScript Playground,
uncomment the first two lines of the class, and the code will compile.